# How can i find a value of a particular key in another Map with non-primitive data type in java?

Tags: java, dictionary, data-structures, hashmap

I have an Map Map1 and another Map Map2..

Map<Key,ProductEntity> Map1;

Map<Key, ProductEntitySecond> Map2;

I want to iterate in map1 and check if that particular key of Map1 is present in Map2. if it is then return the value .

Can someone please give me an idea to solve that type of problem.

Comment: You can simply call map2.get(keyValue).  From Java Docs: "get(Object key)
Returns the value to which the specified key is mapped, or null if this map contains no mapping for the key.". So if not null you know you have a match... This will avoid the necessity of checking if the key exists before hand, but makes necessary to check if not null after.

Comment: Thanks sir for your help. but it not working because the key is an type of entity. and if i compare that entity(key) to another Map2 then it will not match and return null value... so can you give me the another way to solve this....??

Comment: I would suggest you to implement a custom equals method on entity, if the entity has an ID property then it should be used. that way when comparing two instances objects it will not compare by reference but by id.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do something like this:

```
map1
  .entrySet()
  .stream()
  .filter(e -> map2.containsKey(e.getKey()))
  .findFirst()
  .map(e -> e.getValue())
  .orElse(null);
```

So if the key is present in `map2` it'll return the value from `map1` otherwise, it'll return `null`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Stream API](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-streams).

```java
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var map1 = new HashMap<Square, String>();
        map1.put(new Square(2), "two");
        map1.put(new Square(3), "three");
        map1.put(new Square(4), "four");
        map1.put(new Square(5), "five");
        var map2 = new HashMap<Square, String>();
        map2.put(new Square(2), "two");
        map2.put(new Square(3), "three");


        var valuesAlsoInMap2 = map1.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(it -> map2.containsKey(it.getKey()))
                .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
                .toList();
        System.out.println(valuesAlsoInMap2);
    }
}
```

Expected result:

```
[two, three]
```

This is using a simple POJO `Square` to show you it does work with non-primitive types. To see which methods HashMap relies on have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5477452/setting-key-type-in-hashmap-how).

```java
import java.util.Objects;

class Square extends shape{
    private int side;

    public Square(int side) {
        this.side = side;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Square square = (Square) o;
        return side == square.side;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(side);
    }

    @Override
    public double Area() {
        return side*side;
    }

    public int getSide() {
        return side;
    }

    public void setSide(int side) {
        this.side = side;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach using an intersection operation (`retainAll()`) on the two maps' key sets.

```java
Map<Key, ProductEntity> map1 = ...;
Map<Key, ProductEntitySecond> map2 = ...;

Map<Key, ProductionEntity> tmp = new HashMap<>(map1);
tmp.keySet().retainAll(map2.keySet());
Collection<ProductionEntity> shared = tmp.values();
```

This is simple and clean, but it's not the most efficient solution, if that matters in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I will leave you with a very, very simplified example.

If you choose to go with a solution similar to this one I would strongly recommend you to read about how to overwrite Equals and Hashcode: https://www.baeldung.com/java-equals-hashcode-contracts

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class HelloWorld{
     public static void main(String []args) {
            Entity entity1 = new Entity();
            entity1.id = 1L;
            
            Entity entity2 = new Entity();
            entity2.id = 1L;
            
            Map map1 = new HashMap<Entity, String>();
            map1.put(entity1, "one");
            Map map2 = new HashMap<Entity, String>();
            map2.put(entity2, "two");
            
            System.out.println(map1.get(entity1));
            System.out.println(map2.get(entity1));
     }
     
     private static class Entity {
        public Long id;
        
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            return ((Entity) o).id.equals(this.id);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see even two different references but with same id are now considered equals.

Answer (score 0):

for Any java version 8+

```java
List<String> valuesFromMap2WhenKeysAreCommon = 
        map1.keySet().stream().filter(map1::containsKey).map(map2::get).collect(Collectors.toList());
```